# How to have a separator between arabic numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I convert english numbers to arabic numbers with this function :

```
export const e2p = (num) => {
    return num.replace(/\d/g, (d) => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d]);
};
```

In component :

```
import { e2p } from '../../e2p';

{e2p(JSON.stringify(127000))}
```

It works fine and it gives me this result :

```
۱۲۷۰۰۰
```

Now I want to have a separator after three numbers but don't know how like this :

```
۱۲۷,۰۰۰
```

How can I have a separator after three numbers in javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another regex to insert a `,` every 3 digits before end:

```js
replace(/(.)(?=(?:.{3})+$)/g, '$1,')
```

```js
const e2p = (num) => {
    return num.replace(/\d/g, (d) => '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'[d])
      .replace(/(.)(?=(?:.{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
};

console.log(e2p(JSON.stringify(127000)));
console.log(e2p(JSON.stringify(1278000)));
```

#### Brief explanation

- `(.)` match any character, captures it in group 1
- `(?=(?:.{3})+$)` lookahead, if the next sequence ends with `3 * n` characters, replace it with `$1,`(whatever captured in group 1 and followed by a `,`)

---

Also, there's a built-in way to do it. Check [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
const e2p = number => number.toLocaleString('ar-EG');

console.log(e2p(127000));
console.log(e2p(1278000));
```